# google_drive-0.3.0 conflicts with nokogiri

Tags: rubygems

I have just installed the roo gem and when I try and run a ruby script I get the following errors:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1615:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate google_drive-0.3.0, because nokogiri-1.5.2 conflicts with nokogiri (!= 1.5.1, != 1.5.2, >= 1.4.4) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:738:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:764:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:764:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `rescue in try_activate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:206:in `try_activate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from Untitled.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apparently google_drive does not support nokogiri 1.5.2.  I just needed to uninstall nokogiri 1.5.2 and reinstall 1.5.0 and it resolved the error.

Answer (score 2):

The nokogiri line of your get file should look like this:

```
nokogiri, "1.5.0"
```

Then run from command line

```
bundle install
```

Then run

```
bundle update
```

Then change directory via command line to the directory your script is running in and type

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
```

You will get a prompt asking you which version you want to install. 1.5.1 and 1.5.2 must be uninstalled. If both are installed, you'll need to run gem uninstall nokogiri twice.

Once I had done all that, it worked for me in 1.9.3-p125.

It did *not* work simply by setting my gem version in bundler to 1.5.0, it used the a newer nokogiri version anyway.