# Rails: dynamically include helpers per-request at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

My app is has regular users and admins. It has a few rendering helpers which display widgets:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def widget
    "widget"
  end
end
```

For admins, there are extended versions of these widgets:

```
module AdminHelper
  def widget
    "admin-widget"
  end
end
```

The app is configured not to include all helpers by default through `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false`.

When an admin views a page - same controller, same view template -, I want to render an extended version of it by overloading helpers with their AdminHelper version. How do I overload ApplicationHelper with AdminHelper on a per-request basis if the currently logged in user is an admin?

I have tried

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
  before_action :include_backend_helpers

    protected

  def include_backend_helpers
    self.class.helper "pica/backend" if admin_signed_in?
  end
end
```

but this doesn't work unless ApplicationController is reloaded between requests.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to dynamically load code to override the widget is the wrong approach to take. Instead, the `widget` method should decide which version to display on a request-by-request basis. Before we look at some ways to do that, let's explain why the module overriding doesn't work.

---

`ApplicationController` is loaded when your Rails application starts. This automatically includes the `ApplicationHelper` module, which defines the `widget` method. The `AdminHelper` isn't loaded because of the `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers` setting - by setting it to `false` Rails will only load a helper with the same name as the controller.

When a regular user calls the `widget` method, the string `"widget"` is returned. But *as soon as an admin visits the site* the `include_backend_helpers` callback loads your `AdminHelper` module, overriding the `widget` method. The admin gets the string `"admin-widget"` returned - but so does every future visitor to the site! The `widget` method isn't differentiating based on user types.

You could solve this by reloading the `ApplicationController` after each request, but that takes time and will make performance suck. You [*might* be able to unload the module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19755506/3712432), but that seems like an approach fraught with difficulty. You could also try reloading the helper on each request:

```
def include_backend_helpers
  if admin_signed_in?
    self.class.helper "admin/backend"
  else
    self.class.helper "user/backend"
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure that would work, and I wouldn't recommend it.

---

Instead, it seems that it's the widget's job to decide what's appropriate to display. For instance, if this was a navigation component, it should be smart enough to only show admin links. You can still break it out into separate methods:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def widget
    if admin_signed_in?
      user_widget
    else
      admin_widget
    end
  end

  private
  def user_widget
    "widget"
  end

  def admin_widget
    "admin-widget"
  end
end
```

You can use a similar approach with Rails partials - you could have a `_navigation.html.erb` partial that includes either `_user_navigation.html.erb` or `_admin_navigation.html.erb` based on `admin_signed_in?`. Your view includes `<%= render "navigation" %>", and doesn't worry about the internal details.

If you have enough code that the above starts to feel unwieldy, then you should look at [Cells for Rails](https://github.com/apotonick/cells). It's a gem that makes it easier to build encapsulated display components - combinations of controller logic and view code.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I would prefer not to check for user role in every individual widget - that's rather redundant and bothersome when you have dozens of them. For my views and partials, I simply `prepend_view_path '<path_to_admin_overrides>' if admin_signed_in?` - this way I can override them on an individual basis if necessary; all I am missing is a similarly elegant method for dealing with helpers.

Comment: If you've got dozens of components, I'd try to find something I could define as a base class. Then, within the base class, I'd do something like `m = "admin_#{method}"; return self.call(m) if admin_signed_in? && self.respond_to?(m)` inside it. That seems like something you could do with [cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) nicely.

Comment: I'll give that idea a whirl, thanks. For this project I had already taken a look at Cells and dismissed it for conceptual reasons, but I will give it another go.